# updating fragment screen from a listener service

Tags: android, fragment

I'm trying to have one of the tabs in my fragment adapter to update with incoming messages, after studying a bit about fragments I saw no reason I should not be able to do so, but seems that fragments have strange behavior.  Here is the fragment:

```
public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {
    public static ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private EditText recipient;
    private EditText textMessage;
    private static ListView listview;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    class listener extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
        }

        @Subscribe
        public void anotherButtonPress(ButtonEvent event) {
            String newtime = event.itime;
            String newname = event.name;
            messages.add("(" + newtime + ") " + newname + ":");
            messages.add(event.text);

            setListAdapter();
        }

        public void setListAdapter() {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.listitem, messages);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }

}
```

I'm using an event bus called otto, its working ok and I'm sure the message is arriving to this point, but the thing is the screen is not reacting to anything. Do you guys know any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a major problems here. You have a subclass of `Activity` inside a `Fragment`. `Activities` manage `Fragments`, they should not be inside a `Fragment`.

Also, you are registering to the `Bus` too soon. Try changing the registration to `onStart()` in the `Activity` once you fix it.

Comment: am sorry, you mean in the activity nested class create an onstart and do so?

Comment: Yes. Wait, you have a nested `Activity`?

Comment: hehe . very well then, have you any suggestion how to i achieve that then dude? since fragments are like dead's after they get runned once, either i need to refresh fragment every time i have a message or using another suggestion?

Comment: You are going the right way by using an event bus. You can interact with `Fragments` for as long as they are on the screen, sort of like you do with `Activities`.

Comment: well im using logs and seems nothing happenes when it is called! thanks for your efforts any way